# Is upgrading back4app account necessary?

Tags: android, backend, back4app

I want to migrate my app from firebase back-end to using back4app back-end. The free version has limited bandwidth, storage space and cloud functions. I want to run the back-end on a dedicated server. Will I still be required to upgrade my account?

I have not tried anything yet, I am still weighing my options.

Comment: You can try the free plan for testing purposes and see if back4app will really meet your needs. The plans are mainly based on usage, and you can see the limits offered on their pricing page. You can also contact them to see if it's possible to create a tailor-made plan, or suggest the best one based on your usage/expectations.